# How to check whether a BigQuery array includes a NULL value?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

The standard way to check if a [value is in an array](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/arrays#scanning_arrays) in BigQuery is using `IN UNNEST(...)`. For example:

```
SELECT 2 IN UNNEST([0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5]) AS contains_value;
```

What is the suggested way to check if the `NULL` value is in an array? Is there a more direct way than doing:

```
SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST([0,1,1,2,3,null,5]) v WHERE v IS NULL)
```

Is there a more straightforward way for this? And if someone on the BigQuery team or someone familiar with performance/optimizations: does it matter if I add a `LIMIT 1` to the sub-select -- i.e., does the `exists` operator short-circuit automatically once it finds a result or do I have to manually add in a `LIMIT 1` to the subquery?

Comment: It could have been slightly simpler if BigQuery supported `ANY` operator. I think what you posted is the best solution.

Comment: @SalmanA It does have [`ANY_VALUE`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#any_value) - see my answer below.

Comment: I guess you already found an answer: [Work with arrays - Scanning for values that satisfy a condition](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/arrays#scanning_for_values_that_satisfy_a_condition) - and the condition is `col IS NULL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible simple alternative to consider:

```
SELECT ANY_VALUE(x IS NULL) AS contains_value
FROM UNNEST([0, 1, 1, 2, 3, NULL, 5]) AS x;
```

(Could also use `COUNTIF(x IS NULL) > 0` or `MAX(x IS NULL)` in place of `ANY_VALUE(x IS NULL)` but think the latter is preferable).

Not sure how this will compare in terms of efficiency. Something very similar to what you have proposed may be just as good (and closer to what is in the documentation):

```
SELECT EXISTS(
  SELECT * FROM UNNEST([0, 1, 1, 2, 3, null, 5]) AS x
  WHERE x IS null
  LIMIT 1)
AS contains_value;
```

Unless you can get a definitive answer from the Google developers on the `LIMIT` question, I would leave it in - as intuitively the outer select then only needs to look at a single value.